# Facebook API , recuperar primeiro nome

Tags: php, facebook

Estou utlizando a versão 2.9 do Api Facebook em PHP, meu objetivo é recuperar as informações mais básicas.

Pelo que li  na documentação, a única autorização que precisaria é o email, no qual eu já possuo. Primeiro Nome e Último Nome, não precisariam de autorização adicionais

Porém ao executar

```
$loader = require __DIR__ . '\..\vendor\autoload.php';
    $token = $_POST['token'];
    include './Facebook/Facebook.php';
    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'meu id aqui',
        'app_secret' => 'meu segredo aqui',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
        'default_access_token' => $token
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $response = $fb->get('/me',$token);
    $me = $response->getGraphUser();
    echo json_encode(array(
        "resultado" => true, 
        "id" => $me->getId(),
        "name" => $me->getName(), 
        "fields" => $me->getFieldNames(),
        "email" => $me->getEmail(),
        "cover" => $me->getField("cover"),
        "firstname" => $me->getFirstName(),
        "lastname"=>$me->getLastName(),
        "picture" => $me->getPicture()

));
```

Eu somente recebo

1. id
2. nome
3. email

Todos os outros campos são nulos

Ao passar por parametro no `get('/me?fields=email,name,id,lastname,firstname')`, o PHP emite o erro

> Graph returned an error: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (lastname) on node type (User)*

Como recuperar essas informações com a API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o Graph API Explorer para testar suas *queries* antes de fazer a programação:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me?fields=id,name,email&version=v2.9

Na hora de adicionar mais *fields* pode conferir os valores corretos, você está usando `lastname` mas o certo é `last_name`:

[image: fb/me]

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, obrigado.